# Getting the width of videojs progress bar

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to get the current width of videojs'ss progress bar.  I am currently do it like this

```
player.getChild('ControlBar').getChild('ProgressControl').currentWidth()
```

But this gives me an integer (in my case 40) which is clearly not in px. I want the width in px.  How can I do it? And what does this 40 means?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/progress-control.html):

width( num, skipListeners ) - Set or get the width of the component (CSS values)

Therefore all you need is this:

```
player.getChild('ControlBar').getChild('ProgressControl').width(); //gets the width of the component
```

Comment: it is giving me 0